# How to create a custom queryset from a json file

Tags: python, json, django, django-queryset

**Is it somehow possible to create a custom queryset data structure from a given json file?**

I have the json file and I want the queryset in order to use the queryset for presentation with django_tables2 and filtering with django_filters.

The key point is that I do not have any model and I do not want to create a model with the data from json.

I just want to create the queryset.

```
existence = 1
try:
      offer_request = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
      existence = 2
except:
      print("nothing")

if existence == 2:
     offers=json.loads(offer_request.text)
```

The `offers` variable contains my json.

The json is a list of dictionaries.

For example one item is :

```
{'yachtId': 16425620217200198, 'yacht': 'Bravo Kiss', 'startBaseId': 1, 'endBaseId': 1, 'startBase': 'Dubrovnik/ACI Marina Dubrovnik', 'endBase': 'Dubrovnik/ACI Marina Dubrovnik', 'dateFrom': '2020-06-02 00:00:00', 'dateTo': '2020-06-03 00:00:00', 'product': 'Bareboat', 'price': 271.0, 'currency': 'EUR', 'startPrice': 271.0, 'discountPercentage': 0.0}
```

**Is it somehow possible from this data to create a queryset with structure based on the keys of the dictionary data in order to feed my template?**

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking.

Comment: @KenKinder I update the question, hope it is clear now

Comment: No, I'm not sure what you mean still. So you're looking to query all rows where every column matches what's in the JSON?? A queryset is not a "data structure," so that's perhaps where I'm getting confused. It's to query a database. Certainly you can programmatically build a queryset, but there's not a direct relationship between between a data structure like a JSON file and a queryset.

Comment: @KenKinder it was my description wrong. I thought I could create fom scratch a queryset  without having any model related. But obviously i can't. To sum up I want to query all rows where every column matches what's in the JSON  but using django_tables2 in my case. To present data with django_tables2 they must be from a model(ex: MyModel.objects.all()) that's why I am asking if it is possible to turn json to queryset without having a model at all

Comment: So there's no model class at all for `django_tables2`?

Comment: exactly , there's no model class at all for django_tables2

Comment: I see. You won't be able generate a queryset for a table Django doesn't know exists. You can, however, generate models from an existing database: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/legacy-databases/

Answer (score 4):

From what I understood, you need to filter your queries based on your JSON. Considering `offers` have yours JSON, you can use:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(**offers)
```